# Can i create web based drawing tool, the front end is developed in swing?

Tags: java, html, swing, canvas

I'm planning to develop a web based drawing tool using the java backend, what my question is can I use swing as a front end for this application or do I need to go for html canvas kind of technology.

Anyway my preference is to develop the front end using swing but need to know whether is it possible for a web based application.

Comment: *"or do I need to go for html canvas kind of technology."*  If it is achievable using that, it will provide a better user experience than an embedded applet.

Answer (score 1):

Web based usually means that it's available on a website. Swing is not a website. You could use Java Webstart to launch a Swing application, but I wouldn't call that "web based".
Then of course you have applets, but I'd advise against that, since many people have disabled the Java plugin for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kayaman,
Web application mean its a tool runing on netbeans then again it should allow the remote user to connect to the application using their ip addresses.

Comment: Netbeans is an IDE. Nothing can run on Netbeans (and no, just because it has a "run" button doesn't mean your application is running **on** Netbeans, it just means it was started **by** Netbeans). But it seems that what you want is a `Server-Client` program.

Comment: I told u the word netbeans to mention that the tool doesn't needs to run on web browser. Rather it should be seprate application onwhich  several users should be able connect and work.

Comment: Netbeans is a program used to create Java programs, whether they're web applications (i.e. "websites"), applets or stand-alone programs. Saying "Netbeans" doesn't tell you anything about what the program might be like (except that it's most likely Java related). However, like I said, you want to create a server, and a client that connects to the server.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur replies with interest. I agree your point Kayaman, ultimately that should be the way of doing deploy the app on the server and let the user to access. Since still i'm in designing stage i'm unable to decide how am i going to develop. So before starting the development i need to decide how am i going to develop the front end so which only i need to know can we construct a front end using swing whereas the application is a client-server application? That is the one i need to know exactly.